# Why don't consumer laptops have trusted platform modules (TPMs)?

Tags: laptop, security, tpm

I've noticed that only "business laptops" (eg. Dell Latitude series, Lenovo ThinkPad T or W series, etc.) tend to have trusted platform modules (TPMs). In today's world, security is not a business-exclusive topic, and end users can benefit from using very simple, easy-to-use tools like Windows Bitlocker (Vista, 7, 8) just as much as business users can.

Does anyone know why we do not see modern, consumer grade laptops coming with TPMs? Even on business laptops, TPMs are simply an optional component, as they can still be obtained sans the TPM

Answer (score 2):

If consumer laptops had TPMs, how would manufacturers sell the more lucrative "professional" laptops? It's the same reason airline tickets without a weekend cost more. Retailers and manufacturers are always looking for ways to make people who are willing to pay more actually pay more without losing the business of those not willing to pay more. This is one such way.

Comment: I understand the concept you're portraying, but consumers walking into Best Buy aren't going to get a "business class" laptop anyway. I doubt that a single laptop in Best Buy has the option for a TPM, much less actually having one.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan and I doubt the average person walking in to Best Buy to buy a laptop cares if their laptop has a TPM or not.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: Exactly. That means someone who wants a "professional" laptop will have to buy from a higher-priced vendor, which is exactly what laptop manufacturers want. (You think Best Buy tells HP what parts to put in a laptop? Of course not. They just decide which models to carry -- largely consumer/value models.)

Comment: But the average consumer doesn't even *know* to purchase a "professional" laptop. Unless these companies market technologies like TPMs to the masses, they will never even know about them.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan: Exactly. That makes it perfect. If the average consumer knew they wanted a TPM, stores like Best Buy would demand that consumer laptops had them because they'd be losing sales to higher-end outlets and the whole plan would fall apart. (This will probably happen eventually anyway and then laptop manufacturers will have to find some new features to use for this purpose.)

Comment: Average consumers just won't pay more for a TPM, so there's no reason to market or sell laptops with TPMs to them. This scheme will only work if consumers do not value TPMs highly. (If they did, one laptop manufacturer will include TPMs in all their laptops and get a much larger chunk of the consumer market, forcing other manufacturers to do likewise. This only works because typical consumers give roughly a zero value to a TPM.)